# Cortana password bypass CVE-2018-8140

Tags: vulnerability, powershell

Recently a [vulnerability in Microsoft's Cortana](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2018-8140) ([CVE2018-8140](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-8140)) has been patched. Mcafee made a [blog post](https://securingtomorrow.mcafee.com/mcafee-labs/want-to-break-into-a-locked-windows-10-device-ask-cortana-cve-2018-8140/) about it explaining some background information.
 There is also a [video](https://players.brightcove.net/21478975001/rJsQG2JOl_default/index.html?videoId=5796435398001) showing a Proof of Concept, resetting the password of a computer and logging in.

Now I am trying to recreate this PoC purely out of curiosity and interest. I am able to execute a PowerShell script trough Cortana on the login screen but I am unable to reset or change a password. Clearly, I do not have the rights to do this without logging in and thereby accepting the UAC.

The PS script is as follows

```
[console]::beep(2000,1000)
net user Username newpassword
```

I am not asking for programming help but I would like to know if I am missing something important about this vulnerability. Does anyone know how to execute a elevated PowerShell script using the recent [Cortana](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2018-8140) vulnerability? Or the method used to reset the password as shown in the [video](https://players.brightcove.net/21478975001/rJsQG2JOl_default/index.html?videoId=5796435398001).

Comment: The command you are using in not PowerShell. You may be executing it within PowerShell but that doesn't make it a PowerShell command. The PowerShell command you are looking for, if you are a domain member is;
`Set-ADAccountPassword`. I don't know if this is relevant to your PoC but I hope it's helpful.